# Why doesn't my UWP WCF Client's State property reflect actual connection state?

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp

I'm pretty new to WCF and UWP in general, so I'm not too familiar with the pitfalls of either. I've can't figure out why

```
ClientDataObject.LoadedData= await client.GetDataAsync();
```

is throwing a "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot make a call on this channel because a call to Open() is in progress.'" even though I explicitly check for the connection status.

I'm calling this method from the the App's constructor to load a list of strings into the property 'LoadedData' inside a ClientData object I've defined in the App class:

```
    public async void LoadData()
    {

        if (App.client.State == CommunicationState.Opened)                
               ClientData.LoadedData= await client.GetDataAsync();            

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling the channel in a reentrant way?  (Calling `GetDataAsync` before the call to `Open` returns?)

Comment: Is `App.client` even the same as `client` in your code?